# solve this differential equation using substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By observing that $y=x$ is a solution of

$$x^2\cos(x)y'' + (2\cos x - x\sin x)(y-xy') = 0$$

find the general solution in the region $x\in(0,{\pi\over 2})$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Try a solution of the form $y(x)=xf(x)$ after you showed $y=x$ worked. You'll get a new simpler differential equation for $f(x)$.

**EDIT:** Filling in $y(x)=x f(x)$ you should get

$$x^3\cos x f''(x)+x^3 \sin x f'(x)=0 $$

or after simplifying somewhat and a first integration

$$\ln(f'(x))=\ln(\cos x) + c \; .$$

Comment: I get log(df/dx) = sec^2x and I can't solve this...

Comment: You must have made a mistake then, see my edit.

Comment: @Tom: What did you do? Have you overcome the OE?

Answer (score 1):

Or, use the following formula:
$$y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int\frac{\text{e}^{-\int p(x)dx}}{y_1^2(x)}$$ wherein your OE is $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$.

Comment: okay but what are y1 and y2?

Comment: @Tom: As Raskolnikof remarked $y_1=x$ and $y_2$ is the one which you are searching for. In fact, you want $y_c=C_1y_1+C_2y_2$. So both methods can help you to find $y_2$

Comment: @flashdesign2550: Thanks so much :-)

Comment: @BabakS.:$\Large\color{red}{✐}\Large\color{blue}{✎}\Large\color{green}{✔}^+$

Comment: Nice artwork adorning your nice answer!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks so much Amy.

Comment: Hello, dear friend!

Comment: Hello  my dear one. :) I hope you have had a good day up to now. :)